# Test gets stuck when using jest.useFakeTimers() during a database async operation

Tags: async-await, jestjs, nestjs, usefaketimers

I'm trying to do some tests where I need to use fake timers. I'm not showing the complete test here because the issue can be reduced to this. The point is that when I debug, it gets stuck on the `await triggerRepository`. If I remove the fake timers the await resolves and the test goes well. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

```
describe('Get all triggers', () => {

    beforeEach(async () => {
      jest.useFakeTimers();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
      jest.useRealTimers();
    });

    test('trigger status updates true', async () => {
      const savedTrigger = await triggerRepository.findOne(trigger.id);
      expect(savedTrigger.status).toBe(TriggerStatus.TRIGGER_STATUS_REGULAR);
    });
  });
```

I tried advancing the timers after the async call, but the test doesn't reach that line.

I'm using `"ts-jest": "^27.0.3"` and `"jest": "^27.2.5"`